# stm32f103c8t6 turn PA0 to ADC and back to GPIO

Tags: capacitor, stm32, adc, gpio

I have a stm32f103c8t6 which I wish to turn PA0 from ADC mode to GPIO after reading ADC value in order to let the pin to discharge completely and then back to ADC mode for the next reading. how can I do it?

Comment: Same way you are otherwise controlling the IO pins and their mode and direction. How are we supposed to know what language or which libraries you use for that.

Comment: I'm using Keil, and c programming of course

Comment: It is simple, just write few bits into GPIO registers. But GPIO have several modes, which one do you want to switch to ?
- Input floating
- Input pull-up
- Input-pull-down
- Analog
- Output open-drain
- Output push-pull
- Alternate function push-pull
- Alternate function open-drain

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to use MX to generate initialization code for the ADC and for the GPIO and then copy the code.  See below (I initialized PA1 rather than PA0 to generate all the code in one go).

Or do it the old school way, read the datasheet and write the code to deal with the relevant registers.

```
/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

Comment: you mean like this MX_GPIO_Init();//turn to GPIO     MX_ADC1_Init();//back to ADC ?

Comment: Yes, should work.

Comment: well it didnt...

Comment: Assuming you edited the GPIO initialization code to refer to PA0, then maybe the MX code is assuming some initial condition that is not true (shouldn't). I guess reading the datasheet is required.